# Parcelable vs public static. Android patterns

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, android-tabhost, parcelable

I used to use `public static` member variables in order for the starting `Activity` to be able to read the values from the previous `Activity`. I know that it is not a good practice and that it involves risks and limitations like having several instances of the current `Activity` and get the wrong value from the static variable.

Now I use `Parcelable` and pass the parameters in Bundle, but it is a burden sometimes. For example, in my current project I have a `ExpandableListView` and the groups/children stored in a `Map<group name, List<child>>`. This list is in a `Fragment` which is inside a `TabHost` in a `FragmentActivity`. Clicking on a child in the list will launch another `FragmentActivity` with the same structure (`TabHost` and a `Fragment` inside). From this `Fragment` you can edit the child. The problem comes when I need to notify the list that the child has changed. Following the best practices I decided to use a `Broadcast` to send the modified child to the first `Activity`, and let it update the list.

If, instead of a `Parcelable`, I'd use a `public static` variable I just would need to call `notifyDataSetChange()` in the list to refresh because the actual object instance in the `Map` was modified. With the `Parcelable`, even if the object is the same, when it is modified is a different variable in a different memory region. When the first `Activity` receives the `Broadcast`, it needs to loop through all the childs in all the groups to check if it's the same object and replace itself with the broadcasted `Parcelable`.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it supposed to be like this? With this kind of issues I am really tempted to go the public static way :-P

---

PS: Something like this. Long arrow is Broadcast, short arrow is Activity telling the Fragment to replace the child in the Map and refresh the list.

```
Fragment Activity  <----
             |         |
TabHost      |         |
             |         |
Fragment  <--|         |
                       |
Fragment Activity      |
                       |
TabHost                |
                       |
Fragment  --------------
```

Comment: Have you tried populating the expandable list view in the first fragment activity in `onViewCreated` ? Personally, I wouldn't have used a broadcast.

Comment: That would be an option, and would certainly eliminate the need of the Fragment Activity to pass the modified child to the Fragment (actually is just calling a method). But I would still need to loop through all the children in all the groups to check if the id of that child is the same as the id from the modified child received via the broadcast

Comment: If the data fetching operation isn't expensive, why not just fetch the data and put it in the adapter. No need to work on a item-by-item level.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you. I do need to go on a item-by-item level because I need to update the modified object in the list. Because it is not the same reference after passing via Parcelable. If what you mean is to fetch the data again from the server and recreate the adapter, it could potentially be very big and take a few seconds to download, so it is a no go

Comment: Seems like you've understood me quite well ^_^

Ok; In that case - Is `startActivityForResult` an option? If your 2nd fragment is supposed to be returning a change, maybe it's the right way to go? If your activity returned the entire dataset and you just reassigned your member variable to be the one from `onActivityResult`, you could still just do `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: I think that is a great idea! I will need to move the connections from the fragment where you edit the object to the FragmentActivity containing that Fragment, but it should be way easier than the way it is now. Post it as an answer and I will accept it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your first activity, you can `startActivityForResult`. Your second activity can then return the updated dataset. Your first activity can then reassign the data map to whatever `onActivityResult` picks up and you can use `notifyDataSetChanged`.